# Understanding the past participle "been"

Tags: word-usage, present-perfect, past-participles

I am sometimes confused about the past participle "been".

It is used for duration and for other purpose which I don't know. So, my question is about the uses of "been". I can't judge whether the "been" past participle is used for duration or it has other meaning.

I am going to give some examples which are given below. Please add some of your own examples with the "been" participle and with explanation.

1. I didn't tell Sam what happened. He wouldn't have been pleased.
2. I have been teacher for a year.
3. I have been teacher.
4. Has ever been a war in United States?

Comment: I removed the question about "faded", since it doesn't seem to be related to this question. Please ask a new question with your question about "faded". Also, please try to make that more understandable, since I don't understand your question about faded at all.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, "been" is used as a part of the construction known as the 
Perfect Continuous Conditional. This has always the form: Would(n't) have been + [verb (with ed) or adjective]. Would can be replaced with another verb, for example, might. The adjective in the example is pleased. This form is used following a condition that is not true.

In the second example, I have been teacher for a year, the Present Perfect is used. This indicates that I was a teacher last year, and that I still am a teacher. A similiar phrase is:

> I have been teacher since 2014.

The third example sounds a bit unnatural to me.

The fourth example combined the Present Perfect with the word ever. This means the same as "up to now". So the person who asks this question wants to know whether there once was a war in the United States or not.
A similiar construction can be formed with never, for example:

> There has never been a war in the United States.

Comment: In the first example, *"pleased"* can be analyzed as an adjective and not a verb.

Comment: Number 3 sounds odd to you because it is missing an article. It should be *I have been **a** teacher*.